# Maui Using Binding in a custom Control inside a CollectionView

Tags: binding, maui, custom-controls, property-binding, contentview

I've created a Custom Switch control in a ContentView , I'm trying to Bind the toggled State of this Custom switch , so that it changes according to the binded Value, but I'm getting an error when using the Binding.

This is my ContentView Control page.

```
public partial class CustomSwitchView : ContentView, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsToggledProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(IsToggledValue),
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(CustomSwitchView),
        false,
        propertyChanged: IsToggledPropertyChangeEvent
    );

    public bool IsToggledValue
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsToggledProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsToggledProperty, value);
    }

    private void SetSwitchState()
    {
        if (IsToggledValue)
        {
            Switch_Circle.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
            Switch_Body.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(122, 146, 105);
        }
        else
        {
            Switch_Circle.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
            Switch_Body.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255);
        }
    }

    private static void IsToggledPropertyChangeEvent(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        CustomSwitchView switchView = bindable as CustomSwitchView;
        switchView.IsToggledValue = (bool)newValue;
    }
    private void this_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetSwitchState();
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task Tap()
    {
        if (IsToggledValue)
        {

            Switch_Circle.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
            Switch_Body.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255);
            IsToggledValue = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Switch_Circle.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
            Switch_Body.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(122, 146, 105);
            IsToggledValue = true;
        }
    }


   public CustomSwitchView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

I'm new to creating custom controls , so I'm not sure if everything is done correctly.

This is how I'm trying to bind the Toggled State of the Control Inside a CollectionView

```
<DataTemplate>
  <StackLayout>

          <!--ALLERGENIC LAYOUT-->
             <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <ColumnDefinition/>
                   <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Style="{StaticResource PrimaryEntryLabelStyle}" 
                          VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="16" 
                          TextTransform="Uppercase"
                          TextColor="{StaticResource SecondaryTextColor}" 
                          Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                     views:CustomSwitchView x:Name="SwitchView_Allergenics" Margin="0,0,20,0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End"
                             IsToggledValue="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                  </Grid>

        </StackLayout>
</DataTemplate>
```

For some reason the IsToggledValue= {Binding IsSelected} gives me the error :

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

Error   XFC0009 No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "IsToggledValue", or mismatching type between value and property.

I'm not sure how I can bind this specific property so it gets updated, or If im using the wrong approach to this problem, Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

When I use this Custom Switch outside of a collection I can treat it independently and have no problem , the problem comes when using it in a CollectionView and using a Binding to the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties?view=net-maui-8.0)

> The naming convention for bindable properties is that the bindable property identifier must match the property name specified in the Create method, with "Property" appended to it.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty IsToggledProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(IsToggled),
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(CustomSwitchView),
    false,
    propertyChanged: IsToggledPropertyChangeEvent
);

public bool IsToggled
{
    get => (bool)GetValue(IsToggledProperty);
    set => SetValue(IsToggledProperty, value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! such a simple yet huge mistake , simple changing the IsToggledValue property name to IsToggled made everything work perfectly!